# Image to RGB matrix in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am a beginner in Flutter. I want to choose an image from my local and convert it into an RGB array. Can anybody please provide me with the code to do so correctly?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: use loop and get every pixel by pixel and store it in array

Answer (score -1):

You can use this package - [image](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image)

It provides image conversion and manipulation utility functions.

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as Imagi;
```

Here's how to use it to obtain RGB matrix of a file from ImagePicker()-

```
final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
if (image == null) return;
      final imageTemp = File(image.path);
controlImage = imageTemp;
```

Now here's a function for obtaining the RGB matrix -

```
List<List<int>> imgArray = [];
 void readImage() async{

    final bytes = await controlImage!.readAsBytes();
    final decoder = Imagi.JpegDecoder();
    final decodedImg = decoder.decodeImage(bytes);
    final decodedBytes = decodedImg!.getBytes(format: Imagi.Format.rgb);
    // print(decodedBytes);
    print(decodedBytes.length);

    // int loopLimit = decodedImg.width;
    int loopLimit =1000;
    for(int x = 0; x < loopLimit; x++) {
      int red = decodedBytes[decodedImg.width*3 + x*3];
      int green = decodedBytes[decodedImg.width*3 + x*3 + 1];
      int blue = decodedBytes[decodedImg.width*3 + x*3 + 2];
      imgArray.add([red, green, blue]);
    }
    print(imgArray);

  }
```

The array imgArray will contain the RGB matrix

Comment: Can you please provide me a code where it can work?